# Unable to convert Selenium code into Executable Jar

Tags: selenium, export

I am trying to convert my Selenium code(Selenium with TestNG) to the Jar (Executable Jar file) which can be double clicked to execute.
I did some research and found the way to do it. ([Executable Jar File Research - 1](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/11837/how-to-run-all-selenium-test-cases-via-batch-file?answertab=votes#tab-top) & [Executable Jar File Research - 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37225903/how-to-run-selenium-webdriver-test-cases-from-command-line-without-testng-maven?answertab=votes#tab-top))

I tried the ways but not able to do so.
Also, I would point out that my Selenium code does not have main method.

Error: I am not getting any Launch configuration while converting it to Jar.
[image]

Can some tell me where am i going wrong in this?

EDITED CODE:

```
package com.gs.TestSuiteBase;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import com.gs.Access.*;
import com.gs.Global.Constant;
import com.gs.Global.ExcelUtility;
import com.gs.Search.Search;
import com.gs.TestDataLibrary.*;
import com.gs.TestSuiteLibrary.*;
import com.gs.TransactionsCustomer.CustomerBase;

import transactions.*;

public class TestSuiteBase {
    //Driver Declaration
    public static WebDriver driver;

    //Page Object Declaration - Functions
    public Login objLogin = new Login();
    public Search objSearch = new Search();
    public Customer objCustomer = new Customer();
    public Logout objLogout = new Logout();

    //Page object Declaration - Data Library
    public LoginDataLibrary objLoginData = new LoginDataLibrary();
    public CustomerDataLibrary objCustomerData = new CustomerDataLibrary();

    //Page Object Declaration - Suite Library
    public TestSuiteLibrary objTestSuite = new TestSuiteLibrary();
    public TransactionsCustomer objCustomerTestCase = new TransactionsCustomer();
    public CustomerBase objCustomerBase = new CustomerBase();

    @BeforeClass
    public static void main() {
        System.out.println("*******************");
        System.out.println("launching IE browser");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", Constant.driverAccess);
        driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }

    @Test (priority = 1)
    public void getPageTitle() {
        driver.navigate().to(Constant.gavasevaUrl);
        String strPageTitle = driver.getTitle();
        System.out.println("Page title: - "+strPageTitle);
        Assert.assertTrue(strPageTitle.equalsIgnoreCase("Ganaseva Login"), "Page title doesn't match");
    }

    @Test (priority = 2)
    public void login() throws Exception {
        ExcelUtility.setExcelFile(Constant.testDataFileAccess,"LoginData");
        objLoginData.setLoginDataLibraryCompleteData();
        objLogin.performLogin(driver, objLoginData.getLoginName(), objLoginData.getPassword(), objLoginData.getCaptcha());
        objLogin.assertLogin(driver);
        objLogin.assertUserName(driver, objLoginData.getuserFullName());
    }

    @Test (priority = 3)
    public void createCustomer() throws Exception {
        ExcelUtility.setExcelFile(Constant.testSuiteFileAccess,"TestSuiteList");
        objTestSuite.setTestSuiteLibrary(1);
        System.out.println("Suite: " + objTestSuite.getSuiteNo() + " " + objTestSuite.getSuiteName());

        if(objTestSuite.getSuiteToRun().equals("YES")) {
            //Call Customer Base to execute Customer Test Cases;
            objCustomerBase.customerTestCasesExection(driver);
            }
        else {
            System.out.println("Skipped");
            //Set Execution details in "TestSuite.xlsx" file;
            ExcelUtility.setCellData(Constant.testSuiteFileAccess, "Skipped", 1, 9);
        }
    }

    @Test (priority = 4)
    public void logout() {
        objLogout.performLogout(driver);
    }

    @AfterClass
    public void tearDown() {
        if(driver!=null) {
            System.out.println("Closing IE browser");
            driver.quit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do you have main method in your project? i doubt because testng doesn't need one. For a jar file Main method is must.

Comment: Yes, I didn`t had main method in my Script as Testing doen`t need.
But I made change to my script and added a main method to it.
Still, I am not able to get anything in the Launch Config. dropdown.
I have added my edited code in original post.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot create an executable jar without a main method.
Reference: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14506704/how-to-generate-jar-file-with-no-main-method)

Comment: I made change to my script and added a main method to it. Still, I am not able to get anything in the Launch Config. dropdown. I have added my edited code in original post.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, with few code changes, I am able to export my code as an Executable Jar file.

What I observed is:

1. Yes, you NEED to have main method (as I had posted in the edited part of my code)
2. Run your program as "Java Application" 
   and export it.

You can get the detailed info [here](https://www.joecolantonio.com/2014/05/29/selenium-create-an-executable-java-test/)